# Why isn't my Sinatra app working with SSL?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, sinatra

Alright so, I decided to make sure i can get this ssl stuff working BEFORE building the api.. and I feel 95% of the way there.

So, I have a cert and key from namecheap. All should be good there.

Here is my app.rb

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'
require 'openssl'

class MyServer  < Sinatra::Base
  set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

  get '/' do
    "Hello, world!\n"
  end
end

CERT_PATH = './ssl'

webrick_options = {
    :Port               => 443,
    :Logger             => WEBrick::Log::new($stderr, WEBrick::Log::DEBUG),
    :DocumentRoot       => "/ruby/htdocs",
    :SSLEnable          => true,
    :SSLVerifyClient    => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
    :SSLCertificate     => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(  File.open(File.join(CERT_PATH, "server.crt")).read),
    :SSLPrivateKey      => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(          File.open(File.join(CERT_PATH, "server.key")).read),
    :SSLCertName        => [ [ "CN",WEBrick::Utils::getservername ] ],
    :app                => MyServer
}
Rack::Server.start webrick_options
```

I run the program with

```
sudo ruby app.rb
```

And what's interesting is, on localhost (testing from my macbook pro, running El Capitan) i can access https://localhost and it just says the cert isn't trusted, and asks if I want to go in anyway.  Great.

My ec2 instance, however, I can now access via a domain name, one that matches the cert of course. But the site just returns a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (this is what displays in chrome)

But of course, that shows whether or not I run the sinatra server.

Ok, so it sounds easy. Security group, right?

Well, according to ec2, I'm using a security group that has tpc port 443 enabled on inbound. (HTTPS)

So, what gives?  What am I not doing right? Why does it do what I expect on localhost but not on the ec2 instance?

Any help would be super appreciated.

---

Other information:

- The server does appear to be running. sudo ruby app.rb gives me valid info about my cert, followed by

  [2016-01-22 03:36:52] DEBUG WEBrick::HTTPServlet::FileHandler is mounted on /.
  [2016-01-22 03:36:52] DEBUG Rack::Handler::WEBrick is mounted on /.
  [2016-01-22 03:36:52] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2499 port=443
- If I remove webrick and change the port to 80, everything works fine. I can access this app from my site's domain, on http (not https) of course.
- From the local machine, I am getting a response.

$ wget https://localhost

```
--2016-01-22 04:11:48--  https://localhost/ 
Resolving localhost     (localhost)... 127.0.0.1 
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:443... connected. 
ERROR: cannot verify localhost's certificate, issued by ‘/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA’:   
Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority. 
ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches  requested host name ‘localhost’. 
To connect to localhost insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

This seems correct! So, it does seem to be something with the server setup. I can't connect to it. =/ Again. Security group allows 443 and 80.

---

Things added since I asked the question originally, but still hasn't fixed the issue:

- set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

Comment: you should bind to `0.0.0.0` or whatever IP your DNS points to see http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#bind---server-hostname-or-ip-address

Comment: That is a good call. I added it, but nothing changed (updated the code above).  Same results =/

Comment: can you confirm the server runs after you exit your shell, as you should be daemonizing the process, else the process is sent a `SIGINT` after you exit your ssh session and the process dies

Comment: After running 'sudo ruby app.rb' I get a bunch of info from webrick about the ssl cert, and the final lines are:

DEBUG WEBrick::HTTPServlet::FileHandler is mounted on /.
......
DEBUG Rack::Handler::WEBrick is mounted on /. 
......
INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2499 port=443
......

Comment: So, to be clear, I'm not leaving the ssh session.  Should work, yea?

Comment: There are too many possible things that could be wrong, sorry I can't help

Comment: Could you perhaps make a list of those things? I'll go and check each and every one. This has been stressing me out since yesterday.

Comment: you should start with network connectivity, you should check that you can ping the box, and from the public use `nmap` or `nc` to check what ports are open and reachable on the box, you might also want to `tcpdump` the traffic and see if any packet is getting to the box, once you have done all this, then you can determine if it's an app problem (or ssl) which I don't think it is

Comment: Thanks, I'll do all of that.  I'm not a systems guy, so a lot of this is new to me. I really do appreciate your help. As I've added to the original post, if I run a basic sinatra app on port 80, it works just fine. I can get the responses I'm looking for.  Not sure if that helps any.  Gonna go through your list now and make sure everything checks off.

Comment: to clarify you are running `nc` or `nmap` from anywhere on the internet NOT on the box, and you are running `tcpdump` ON the box. e.g: `nmap -p 443 www.google.com`(change www.google.com to your domain name) and run `sudo tcpdump tcp and port 443` on the box, you should see output that you understand with `nmap` and if traffic is getting to the box you should tcp packets with `tcpdump`

Comment: ping works. 
----- 
nmap? it reports: Host is up (0.013s latency). 
----- 
but then shows
PORT    STATE  SERVICE --- 
443/tcp closed https

Comment: :) there lies your problem, port 443 is either not bound to or is not open to allow connection from the public internet, to confirm if it is bound to run `sudo lsof -i :443` on the server or `sudo netstat -antp | grep 443`, if those return something reasonable, then it's a firewall problem

Comment: after running `sudo tcpdump tcp and port 443` and then hitting the site with `https://{mydomain.com}` I see a bunch of logs that seem to report my ip address (mentions comcast) and ends with this (not sure if this helps): Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 2326089994, win 0, length 0

Comment: that's a reset tcp packet, but it's not helpful if I don't see the entirety, you should run the last set of things I posted just now

Comment: ok! `sudo lsof -i :443` returns `COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    1645 root    5u  IPv4  11063      0t0  TCP localhost:https (LISTEN)`

and `sudo netstat -antp | grep 443`

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:443           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1645/ruby`

I honestly don't know what to make of that. This is why I'm an apps guy, not a sysadmin guy :P

Comment: So, let's say it's a firewall thing. Are changing the ec2 security groups not enough?

Comment: I don't know enough about how EC2 works to know what security groups does, but what you posted shows your sinatra app correctly binds, if I see the full tcpdump output, I might be able to guess where the problem is, I am almost positive it's firewall related, you can also check if you have firewalls enabled locally on the box with `sudo iptables -L -v -n`

Comment: `sudo iptables -L -v -n` gives (this is a long one sorry)

`Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 8 packets, 661 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 1032 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination `

Comment: ok that's no local firewall, I am sorry I really can't help :(

Comment: ok thanks so much for the help you did give. It seems not app related, right?  im looking into the ec2 instance now. I'm checking out something called vpc (virtual private cloud) to see if that could be blocking anything?  If anyone else reads this stuff and has ideas, or if something comes to you later @bjhaid, please let me know. It feels so close.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101364/discussion-between-jp-and-bjhaid).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally you don't want any ruby webservers actually handling SSL. You make them serve plain HTTP (that is accessible only via localhost). Then you install a reverse proxy that handles all of the SSL communicate.

For example

1. Install nginx (reverse proxy) and configure it to listen on port 443.
2. Set your
   ruby app server to listen on port 127.0.0.1:80 (accept local
   connections only)
3. All requests hit nginx, which strips the SSL,
   and send the plain HTTP request to your ruby webserver.

A very simple nginx config to get you started:

```
ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your.key;
ssl on;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name you.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;  # your ruby appserver
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this :D Later or tomorrow. I'll report back.

Comment: I'm having trouble with this configuration. On step 2, is it mandatory to "accept local connections only"?

Comment: Yes, make it localhost only, because nginx (which is on the same host - hence "localhost") will be the only one proxying connections from the outside world